# Saving Custom Field Data before Publish

Tags: custom-field, content, save-post, draft

When creating a page or a post WordPress lets the content (title, body, featured image) be saved when using Ctrl + S. The Custom Fields do not save in the same way (in this case I'm using Advanced Custom Fields as well, but it happens without this plugin).

Does anyone have a solution for saving this data in the same way? In this case Publishing isn't an option.

**UPDATE**: If I click the "Save draft" button the Custom Fields save. The ctrl + S save only seems to be in scope when in the content area. Is there an easy way to change this to be a global post ctrl S? The "Save Draft" button thankfully removes the urgency, but that would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

I just [wrote a plugin](http://codearachnid.github.io/wp-keyboard-save/) that does just that. <s>It's been submitted to the WordPress.org plugin repo earlier this week and hopefully should make an appearance soon.</s> The plugin is [officially in the WordPress.org repo](http://wordpress.org/plugins/keyboard-save/). In short what you are looking for is a way to have the following code available on your post editor:

```
jQuery(window).bind('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
        if(String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase() === 's' ) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if ( typeof wpkeysave_save_trigger !== 'undefined' ){
                // harsh way to save draft/publish/update
                jQuery( '#' + wpkeysave_save_trigger ).trigger( 'click' );
            }

        }
    }
});
```

**Update:** The plugin is [officially in the WordPress.org repo](http://wordpress.org/plugins/keyboard-save/) and will be actively maintained.